# Which would be one easy,reliable and secure way (preferably the best one) to check that a date taken by an Android App is the real date?

Tags: android-development

By easy I mean easy to implement in code.

By reliable I mean that it doesn't depend sources who might fail under which there is no good control.

By secure I mean that it cannot be worked around or that if it could be worked around it would be pretty complicated.

The best solution I can think about for the moment is trying to check that the user has automatic date and hour and automatic time zone enabled. I thought this could be worked around by enabling flight mode, or maybe some other option, but at least in my smartphone, it returns to correct date. Guess there are some things about getting the date in phones I don't understand, anyway I can't be sure this works for all smartphones.

I know about other methods like using some NTP server, but I think this would add unnecesary complexity and less reliability.

I'd like to hear suggestions about which would be a good way to do this.

PS: I'm editing per request.

My app allows to make a certain action in the app only once per week.

It's not something that important what happens if the user manages to trick the app into making it believe that's another date, I don't really care much about maybe a 5% of users tricking the app to believe it's another date, but for this to happen at least all trivial ways in which the date retrieval could be worked around shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve here? But in general, once someone has physical control of the hardware, you can't trust anything from that hardware.

Comment: I'm trying to detect that the date set in the phone is the same date there's in reality, sure, someone who has high technical knowledge might be able to trick an App that makes the check into accepting a false date, but I think that for the common user, it would be enough with the solution I've proposed (checking date, hour in time zone) if date sets to correct whatever the case if their options to have them automatic are enabled.

Comment: If you look at your watch, are you sure that it's the real date ? How can you tell for sure that it's the real date ?

Comment: I cannot, but my phone watch has always properly given a pretty good aproximation for it, as long as the options I'm mentioning have been set for example. This would be enough.

Comment: It would be enough if there's not some easy way to trick those options.

Comment: Please give some more context. Why and how much does this matter? If it's that important why trust the client?

Comment: Secure what against what? You can't ask us to design and evaluate a security design in a vacuum. A cereal box will secure a bag of cheerios against gravity but it won't secure a wad cash from the baby sitter.

Comment: Secure that a real date (or good approximation of it) is taken against the user making the app believing somehow that the date is another one than the one that's at least extremely likely to be at least a very good approximation of the real one.

Comment: The simplest way is to make the app connect to a server to take the action. You're in control of the server and its time, unlike the client device.

Answer (score 1):

How can your app know that the phone uses the real date and that it was not tampered with ?

1. Look for an authoritative source, like an NTP server, hoping that the user has not the skills and equipment to hijack your NTP request
2. Look around to other sources to see if they have the same date than you:

   - For example, you could use the [GPS time](http://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/gps/timsys.html), and check if it's compatible with the date.  I'm not sure of how to get the GPS time on android, but [`GnssClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssClock.html) seems a good start, to look for.  I imagine that method [`getFullBiasNanos()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GnssClock.html#getFullBiasNanos()) in particular could help.  The good thing is that it's very difficult to hijack a GPS signal.
   - Query a popular news site to compare if dates are compatible (but then, you'd better go to an NTP server directly).
3. Make your own consistency check, by logging every hour the date and time in UTC and comparing the current UTC time, with the previous time.  This ensures that the user cannot back-date his device.  If you can do this and compare the difference to a timer that measures the elapsed time between the two events, it would even be more useful.  But honestly, if you fear that the user light tamper the system, he might tamper the log, so you need to encrypt it.  This again is at least as complex as querying an NTP server.

Comment: If the phone has been tampered with, you don't need to hijack the GPS signal, you could just hijack the `GnssClock` library.

Comment: @JörgWMittag true! But I think that the risk is lower, as the gps signal is not the usual source of true time. Anyway, you could check the validity of the library's signature.